# foreach associative array PHP SQL

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

My query returns the following :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
    array(3) {
    ["id_fiets"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["naam"]=>
    string(7) "Assista"
    ["foto"]=>
    string(15) "img/assista.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
    array(3) {
    ["id_fiets"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["naam"]=>
    string(10) "Cannondale"
    ["foto"]=>
    string(19) "img/cannondale.jpeg"
  }
 /*More results here, not displaying them.*/
}
```

Now i need to loop through the following bit of code to display them correctly on the website :

```html
  <div class="fiets">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="" alt="fiets">
        </a>
        <div class="fietssub">
            <p>naam</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where `<a href="#">` should be `<a href="page.php?fietsid=1">`,
`<p>naam</p>` should be `<p>Assista</p>` and last,
`<img src="" alt="fiets">` should be `<img src="img/assista.jpg" alt="fiets">`

I know i have to do it with a foreach loop but i find it hard to do how so I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I have, I tried working with the foreach loop.. I think i have to use multiple loops at the same time which for me is still confusing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should learn `foreach` it is easy. The method isn't tested but It should give you the idea of how `foreach` works. Goodluck :)

```
<?php
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
?>
    <a href="page.php?fietsid=<?php echo $arr['id_fiets']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo $arr['foto']; ?>" alt="fiets">
    </a>
    <div class="fietssub">
        <p><?php echo $arr['naam']; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
   }
?>
```